# How to disallow highlighting selection text by USER but not for unless especially only by SCRIPT?

Tags: javascript, css, google-apps-script, copy, textselection

I have the script to can be make something conflict each others and make me also confuse to solve it. Just through to the point see at my script below :

**====================================== CSS ==================================**

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
outline-style: none;
user-select: none;
```

And the meaning at the lines above for make of user to disallow to selecting the text. And the function of javascript to help process of ***CopyText*** function to keep running selecting text then that will copying it to clipboard after that only just for the script of this function to allowing to selecting text. See the Javascript at the below :

**======================================= JS ===================================**

```
function toClipboard(e) {
  var cell = e.parentNode,
        copyText = cell.getElementsByTagName('span'),
        selection = window.getSelection(),
        range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(copyText[0]);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
    document.execCommand('copy');
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Then the **HTML** for running all script an above to aplicable in table scene. See at the below :

**======================================= HTML ================================**

```
...
<tr OnClick=highlight(this)>
    <td>test to copy this text <button onclick=toClipboard(this)><small>Copy</small></button></td>
...
```

***NB :***  *Now the problem is the function of **toClipboard** don't want work. What should I do for this?  And sorry about my english and thanks in advance to have taken your time to read this thread!*

Comment: How is this related to Apps Script?

Comment: @ziganotschka I implementing this and using it into tag of htmlService ...

Comment: Try the new [api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard#Clipboard_availability)

Comment: @TheMaster Hehe ..  till today I still dont know what means the about of the api is ???